# How to create flow data from firebase to react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flux, nosql

I'm trying to connecting firebase real time database to react using flux, i'm not including the action just to shorten the code, my code:

```
// in React parent component
componentDidMount() {
    // connecting to firebase when component completely mounted
    rootRef.child('nodes').on('value', snap => {
        // passing snap to Store and emiting changes
        Store.inject(snap)
    })
    Store.on('connect', this.listenDatabase)
}

listenDatabase() {
    this.setState({
        dataReceived: true,
        rootData: Store.getRootData()
    })
}


// in Store.js
inject(snap) {
    const data = snap.val();
    // do something with data
    // ...
    this.result = /* some data turned into array or object */
    this.emit('connect')
}
```

My code works, but the question is this flow is good practice?

Answer (score 0):

you need to write getRootData function

```
// in Store.js
    inject(snap) {
    const data = snap.val();    // do something with data    // ...    this.result = /* some data turned into array or object */    this.emit('connect')

     getRootData(){
        return this.result
     }
```